# What is the difference between react-navigation's StackNavigator and SwitchNavigator?

Tags: react-navigation

As of this writing, the [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/switch-navigator.html) don't provide a description of `SwitchNavigator`'s purpose.

I've tried using both `StackNavigator` and `SwitchNavigator` interchangeably and I personally cannot spot a difference. *Although I'm certain there is.*

Can anyone explain what the added benefit of `SwitchNavigator` is over `StackNavigator` ? Or a scenario where one might use it over the other?

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. " Could somebody tell me how could this question get any more specific? Unless the user has authored the library and knows more about it, I think this question is specific enough.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a description from React Navigation:

> The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a
>   time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes
>   to their default state when you switch away. This is the exact
>   behavior that we want from the authentication flow: when users sign
>   in, we want to throw away the state of the authentication flow and
>   unmount all of the screens, and when we press the hardware back button
>   we expect to not be able to go back to the authentication flow. We
>   switch between routes in the SwitchNavigator by using the navigate
>   action.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html

Comment: Thanks for finding that.  They should add this definition to the main SwitchNavigator documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me as well :)
I've opened a Pull Request to add it to the doc : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation.github.io/pull/149